clang AST writer add new line after an expr
I'm trying to add some code after a matched expression.
However, insertAfter(expr, "new code") adds the code between the expression and the ending semicolon ; of the expression.
What's the best way to add code after the semicolon? If I need to use insertBefore or insertAt, how do I find the source location of the next line?

Expression is what is before a semicolon. Expression + semicolon is statement, but the standard doesn't define it. You have answered your question in the last sentence.
